# how to hide keyboard in jquery mobile programmatically on focus()

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, cordova

I want to hide the keyboard on Focus(),but when `$(".ui-input-text").focus();` it will automatically open the keyboard .

I just want to hide in particular screen ,I have test with `document.activeElement.blur();`
but it also did not  focus() on input .

Comment: This seems perverse. You want to focus a user input field, but disable the input method? Why?

Comment: i have my custom keyboard on screen

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When submitting a form, at times, the iOS Keyboard may not automatically close. This is quite a usability issue as Users should not be required to manually close the Keyboard for use-cases in which they would otherwise not expect the need do so.

A simple solution for this can be implemented by invoking the blur method on document.activeElement, which effectively allows one to programmatically hide the keyboard:

```
// automatically close the keyboard on iOS
document.activeElement.blur();
```

More about HTML5 and Mobile application events ..

http://www.ericfeminella.com/blog/2012/12/27/ios-html5-input-element-tips/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#yourElement').blur();
```

It will hide the virtual keyboard.

Comment: i have used this one but when i use it also not focus () on input

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://uihacker.blogspot.in/2011/10/javascript-hide-ios-soft-keyboard.html)

```
var hideKeyboard = function() {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $("input").blur();
};
```

**Edited :**
another option

```
$('.clr').after('
        //<input tyep="checkbox" 
        <input type="checkbox"
               id="focusable" 
               style="height:0;
               margin- left:-200px;
               clear:both;" />');
$('#focusable').focus(); `
```

Comment: but issue was that when i add this code it  also loose the focus from the input

Comment: @Gamex you can assing focus again as shown in another option.