# Hide keyboard on mobiles after firing *select* jQuery event

Tags: android, jquery, autocomplete

On my little site ([link](http://raigle.com/a.php)) I have a search input with jQuery Autocomplete and side menu. Both Autocomplete and menu use **select** event to deliver content using AJAX.

**The problem**. On Android, when you type a search word and choose Autocomplete, the keyboard is not hiding. The same happens when you type a word and then touch the menu. Menu select event is firing, but the keyboard isn't hiding. Guess, iPhones have the same problem.

I looked for the answer on stackoverflow, but haven't found appropriate jQuery roundabout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582318/2977133) answer, using

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

works on iOS and android to make the keyboard go away.